# SQL aggregation to get Avg of category

Tags: mysql

Two tables, one with book genre and another with price. How can I achieve avg price of each book category? I am new to SQL I am having a hard time finding the right content for my problem. Maybe I am missing the proper keywords to search.

```
-- create
CREATE TABLE BookGenre
(
  genre_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  genre TEXT NOT NULL
   
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE BookTable
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  cost INTEGER,
  genre_id INTEGER references BookGenre(genre_id)
);
```

```
-- insert
INSERT INTO BookGenre VALUES (1,'fic');
INSERT INTO BookGenre VALUES (2,'Nov');
INSERT INTO BookGenre VALUES (3, 'com');
```

```
INSERT INTO BookTable VALUES (1,'a',10,1);
INSERT INTO BookTable VALUES (2,'b',5,1);
INSERT INTO BookTable VALUES (3, 'c',20,2);

INSERT INTO BookTable VALUES (4,'d',10,2);
INSERT INTO BookTable VALUES (5, 'e',40,3);
```

```
select G.genre,B.name,avg(B.cost) as avgGen FROM BookTable as 
B join BookGenre as G On B.genre_id = G.genre_id group by G.genre,B.name;
```

Doing this gives me results that I am not expecting.

Output:

```
genre   name    AvgGen
fic       a.    10.0000
fic.      b     5.0000
Nov.      c     20.0000
Nov.      d     10.0000
com       e     40.0000
```

I want an average of a and c on 1 and 2, avg of c and d on 2 and 3 and e on last. In other words, the average of same category of books and each book cost.

Also adding  B.cost gives me an error.

Comment: Hi! Let me see if I understood your problem correctly. Do you want to list every book on every category with the average price for that book's category or only the categories with the average book price for each of them?

Answer (score 0):

Your current query is taking the average price of all books that have the same genre and same name (what most probably will be a single item).

If you want to list the average price for the genre for each book, you will have to change your query to fetch that with a JOIN and/or a subquery like so:

```sql
SELECT G.genre, B.name, (SELECT AVG(cost)
  FROM BookTable
  WHERE genre_id = B.genre_id
) AvgGen
FROM BookTable B
INNER JOIN BookGenre G ON g.genre_id = B.genre_id
ORDER BY G.genre, B.name
```

Or, a more complex example joining a subquery:

```sql
SELECT G.genre, B.name, G.AvgGen
FROM BookTable B
LEFT JOIN (SELECT G2.genre_id, G2.genre, AVG(B2.cost) as AvgGen
  FROM BookGenre G2
  LEFT JOIN BookTable B2 ON G2.genre_id = B2.genre_id
  GROUP BY G2.genre_id, G2.genre
) as G ON G.genre_id = B.genre_id
ORDER BY G.genre, B.name
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9429e3f/